# How to efficiently use sub parsers in Python argparse

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I'm writing a command line interface using the argparse module in Python. In total I have 5 difference cantons I want to call from the command line, and I've assigned them all a separate command line subparser as follows:

```
FUNC_DESC = 'Function description.'
FUNC_YHLP = 'Argument description'

FUNC_PRSR = SUBPARSERS.add_parser('function_name', description=FUNC_DESC)
FUNC_PRSR.set_defaults(func=my_func)
FUNC_PRSR.add_argument('-a', '--arg', help=UPDATE_YHLP)
```

The problem with this method is that every time a user wants to call a function from the command line, the script needs to recreate these sub parsers before actually running the desired function. This takes a very small small but noticeable amount of time. I expect users to be calling functions dozens of times over (with different arguments) and this delay is annoying and seems like wasted time.

Is there a more efficient way to set up a command line interface? I'm open to using something other than argparse.

Comment: While I contributed an answer to the linked duplicate, that case required DB queries.  I don't see such a delaying operation here.  In timing tests, following your model, I can create a main parser and 5 subparsers in 3.2ms, that's roughly .5ms per parser.  In a script, the difference in run time for setting up 5 subparsers vs 10 barely rises above the startup noise.

Comment: If you don't like the duplicate, I'd suggest expanding the example so we can actually see and test the efficiency issue that's bothering you.

Comment: I added an answer to the duplicate link that more closely reproduces this case.  I'm pleasantly surprised at how well I was able to create a lazy subparser mechanism.  But it doesn't shorten the startup time.